# Display each bit in a char C++

Tags: c++

I want to display each bit in a char. This however does not work :

```
    char flags = byteFromFile();
    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
        int tmp = ( flags >> i ) & 0x2;
        cout << tmp;
    }
    cout << endl;
```

What's wrong with this code?

I get only zeros but the byte has a value of 3 ( I looked it up with a debugger ).

Comment: What output do you get, and what were you expecting?

Comment: "Does not work" what

Comment: Please learn how to compose a [testcase](http://sscce.org) and to explain problems with rigour and precision. Your edit is far from sufficient.

Comment: `std::cout << std::bitset<8>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << '\n';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your code.

1. You are using `& 0x2` instead of `& 0x1`.
2. You are printing the least significant bit first.

The following should fix both.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned char flags = argv[1][0];
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << ((flags >> i) & 0x1);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to display bit, you should do `& 0x1` rather than `& 0x2` - after all, your result should be either zero or one.

Comment: I still get only zeros. I read in a different question that you want 0x2 for the first bit, 0x3 for the first two etc. So why 0x1?

Comment: @Davlog: I don't know where you read that, but it's obviously wrong, or you misunderstood it.

Comment: @Davlog 0x1 is the first, 0x2 the second and 0x3 is the first and the second together.

Comment: @Davlog, All you need to do is convert those numbers to binary and you'll see which bit(s) they match up with.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code, but I had to construct my own testcase to find them. Next time, please do this yourself. In particular, you reference an unknown function `byteFromFile()`.

Fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const unsigned char flags = 0x03;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        std::cout << ((flags >> i) & 0x1);

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

You were `AND`ing the wrong value, plus you really want the input to be `unsigned char`.

Still, if you really want to do this properly, look into `std::bitset` which absolves you from needing to mess around with loops and shifting.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main() 
{
    char c = 'A';

    for ( size_t i = CHAR_BIT; i != 0; --i )
    {
        std::cout << ( ( unsigned char )c >> ( i - 1 ) & 1 );
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
01000001
```

It corresponds to ASCII code 65 of 'A'.